# Cannot locate base.html in root directory. Suspect template loader as problem

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am new to python and Django. I have a **base.html** file in my root directory.  I have a **hello_world.html** file in my personal_portfolio app's template file that contains `{% extends "base.html" %}` in **hello_world.html**.  I have the appropriate entry in the `'DIRS':` settings of my personal_portfolio project.  I get a **template not found** error for base.html.

In the debug info I see reference to **'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source'**.  My impression is that when `'APP_DIRS':` is `True`, this loader is responsible for automatically loading each apps template file in a list of directories to search for templates.  I see no reference to  ' **'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source'** which I understand is responsible for adding directories in the `'DIRS':` setting to the search list.  This is how **base.html** should be located.  However, it seems that no matter what I do only the **'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source'** loader is used.
I even tried including a setting for `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` in **settings.py**.

What I did as a workaround is modify the the **app_directories.py** module to add the directory I am pointing to in the `'DIRS':` setting.  Here is the app_directories modification in **E:\Python Programs\Web Projects II\rp_portfolio\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\app_directories.py**.

```py
#**************  Revised app_directories.py
"""

Wrapper for loading templates from "templates" directories in INSTALLED_APPS
packages.
'''

from django.template.utils import get_app_template_dirs

from .filesystem import Loader as FilesystemLoader

class Loader(FilesystemLoader):

    def get_dirs(self):
# ##      return get_app_template_dirs('templates')
        #esr revised 8/22/19
        dirtup = get_app_template_dirs('templates')
        dirlst = list(dirtup)
        dirlst.append('E:\\Python Programs\\Web Projects II\\rp_portfolio\\templates')
        dirtup2 = tuple(dirlst)
        print('\n****************** app_directories.py:  dirtup2:',                    dirtup2,'\n')
        print('\n****************** app_directories.py: __file__ value:',__file__,'\n') !             

        return dirtup2
```

Above code worked and enabled locating "base.html" worked.

Why doesn't **base.html** load the normal way?

**settings.py** in personal_portfolio

```py
"""

Django settings for personal_portfolio project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
print('\n***********BASE_DIR:', BASE_DIR,'\n')
projecttemplates = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates\\'))
print('\n*******projecttemplates:', projecttemplates,'\n')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '-lql%2p2@5xy^s)fw@poz7qiw@r3rj%#_)$aufs)dpe*xs@xgr'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'hello_world',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'personal_portfolio.urls'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
 )

#   'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',

MASTER_BASE_DIR = BASE_DIR



TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(MASTER_BASE_DIR,'templates\\')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                  ],
        },
    },
]

print('\n************ TEMPLATES:',TEMPLATES,'\n')
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'personal_portfolio.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Directory Structure[image]

Comment: Isn't your whole app_directiories.py commented due to lack of `"""` after description?

Comment: The actual code has the ''' in it.  I've added it to the sample code above.  The fact is that the only time "base.html" is located is when the patched app_directories.py is included.

Comment: The full error message should say which directories Django tried. I would remove the trailing `\\`.

Comment: You shouldn’t post your secret key - make sure you change it before you deploy your site to production.

Comment: @Alasdair, Assuming that's what you meant, I removed the trailing '\\' at the end of my DIRS: entry under TEMPLATES in settings.py.  That did it. Thank you.  Apparently Python doesn't like a trailing backslash at the end of a directory path.

Comment: Django suggests using forward slashes even on Windows. I don’t think that a trailing `/` would cause an issue.